# PHP cURL error SSL certificate problem unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

So I'm just trying out twilio but I seem to be having some trouble with cURL errors; specifically:

***cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json***

Here is some important notes:

- This is in PHP
- Using Laravel framework

Basically I'm using direct to a controller and using a response.

**SmsController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class SmsController extends Controller
{
    public function send()
    {
        $id     = env('TWILIO_APP_ID');
        $token  = env('TWILIO_APP_TOKEN');
        $from   = env('TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER');
        $to     = env('TWILIO_TONG_NUMBER');
        $url    = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'.$id.'/Messages.json';

        $client   = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'auth' => [$id, $token],
            'form_params' => [
                'From'  => $from,
                'To'    => $to,
                'Body'  => 'hello from the other side! - ryan :)'
            ]
        ]);

        return response()->json(['test'=> 'worked']);
    }
```

Before anyone asks; yes I've spent a day reading other peoples problems related to cURL; and I was unable to find any solutions.

I tried adding certs to my ...\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt

I didnt work.

I tried re-installing Git.

It also didnt work.

When I run php -m I cal see curl in PHP Modules. But I'm not sure if it up to date how to check or if its not the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: @Hackinet I don't believe so; they're using xampp and wamp; I have mamp though.